# How to create a QTMovieView within an NSWindow that is able to be moved and resized within that window?

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, qtkit

I am creating a Cocoa NSWindow, inside this (via IB) are a QTCaptureView, QTMovieView and various buttons and text fields.

Programmatically, I have done the following:

Created a new QTMovie:

```
- (BOOL)readFromURL:(NSURL *)url ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    QTMovie *movie = [QTMovie movieWithURL:url error:outError];
    if (movie){
        [self setMovie:movie];
    }
    return (movie != nil);
}
```

and then set up the QTMovieView accordingly:

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];

    [movieView setShowsResizeIndicator:YES];
    [[movieView window] setShowsResizeIndicator:NO];    

    mainWindow = [aController window];
    [[mainWindow contentView] addSubview:movieView];
}
```

The movie plays fine and my web cam is captured and displayed.
I have two problems that I can not seem to solve;

1. I would like to resize the QTMovieView according to the QTMovie Aspect ratio. I kind of do this within IB but the QTMovieView window remains the same size, only the movie plays at the desired size.
2. I would also like to resize and move the QTMovieView around the NSWindow.

I have searched the web and haven't found an answer, so most probably it's not something that can't be done but a problem with my code.

I have been working from the 'QTKit Application Tutorial' document.

**[Edit 25/05/2012]**

On page 28 onwards it describes how to resize the window to the movies natural size attribute. I followed this but the main window resized and not the QTMovieView window.

```
[[movieView window] setContentSize:contentSize];
```

So I guess my understanding was incorrect, and the QTMovieView window is the main window. There is NO additional child window that the QTMovieView window sits in, just the one I placed it in!

**[Edit 26/05/2012]**

In Cocoa there is only one window and there is no concept of child windows!
To allow the QTMovieView to be dragged you have to get it to accept mouse events.
To do this you have to subclass it and override;

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstMouse:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

Basically read Apples 'Handling Mouse Events' document.

As for resizing, I'm working on that now.

**[End Edit]**

Any ideas would be most appreciated.
Thanks.